# Callin ascx.cs function from .ascx

Tags: c#, javascript, ascx

this is my sample code. I'm tryin to call the method `calculateCoordinates()`, which is inside a javascript on a .ascx file tried `OnClick` but it won't work and now i'm trying `OnClientClick` and is not working either.

```
 //button
 <asp:Button CssClass="button" ID="CalcCoord_Btn" runat="server" Text="Calcular Coordenadas" OnClientClick="javascript: calculateCoordinates();"/>
 //also tried 
 <asp:Button CssClass="button" ID="CalcCoord_Btn" runat="server" Text="Calcular Coordenadas" OnClientClick="calculateCoordinates();"/>
 <asp:Button CssClass="button" ID="CalcCoord_Btn" runat="server" Text="Calcular Coordenadas" OnClientClick="javascript: calculateCoordinates(); return false"/>


 //.ascx javascript 
 <script type="text/javascript">
function calculateCoordinates() {
     alert("calculateCoordinates");
     var AddressLn1 = document.getElementById("AddressLine1");
     var AddressLn2 = document.getElementById("AddressLine2");
     var State = document.getElementById("State");
     var Town = document.getElementById("City");
     var Postcode = document.getElementById("ZipCode");
     var Country = document.getElementById("State");


     var address = AddressLn1.value + ', ';
     address += AddressLn2.value + ', ';
     address += Town.value + ', ';
     address += Postcode.value + ', ';
     address += Country.value;

     // Make REST call to get geocoded information (that is, the coordinates for the address)
     // This will use your call back procedure and return result in JSON format
     var geocodeRequest = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?query=" + encodeURI(address) + "&output=json&jsonp=GeocodeCallback&key=" + credentials;
     CallRestService(geocodeRequest);
     //return false;

 }

 function CallRestService(request) {
     alert("CallRestService");
     var script = document.createElement("script");
     script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
     script.setAttribute("src", request);
     document.body.appendChild(script);
 }

 function GeocodeCallback(result) {
     alert("GeocodeCallback");
     var Lat = document.getElementById("hdnfldVariableLat");
     var Long = document.getElementById("hdnfldVariableLong");

     if (result &&
            result.resourceSets &&
            result.resourceSets.length > 0 &&
            result.resourceSets[0].resources &&
            result.resourceSets[0].resources.length > 0) {


         Lat.value = result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].point.coordinates[0];
         Long.value = result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].point.coordinates[1];
         var location = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(Lat.value, Long.value),
         pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(location, { text: '2', draggable: true }); 
      }
   }
</script>
```

also tried "return false" at the end of `calculateCoordinates()` method. but it won't even give me one of those alerts to see if the method in fact is being called... i know it's simple but what am i doing wrong? the method `calculateCoordinates()` was tested and works like a charm so i know it works.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any other JS errors? GeocodeCallback() function is missing a closing curly brace (}). - Edit: Is actually missing two, one for the if, and one for the function.

Comment: the curly brace is fine is just that i missed it when i was copy pasting.. the script tags I added them here.. but the method does have the two missing braces.

Comment: I was able to get the function working (without the body of the function of course). What are AddressLine1 and 2? Are they Textboxes? Where are they? Are they part of the ascx, or part of a .aspx?

Comment: they are part of the ascx and the id's are fine because i'm using them on another function

Comment: Does the function get to the alert at least? Where does it break? Any errors in the console?

Comment: Ok, so it does not get to the alerts it means you have some kind of JavaScript error somewhere.

Comment: I know that a control inside a page gives the textbox and other elements a different Id that the one I entered. but but this purpose on the code i have the correct id's but since they are too long i'm using in here the id's i gave them.

Comment: I know that maybe i have a problem in the GeocodeCallback(result) in the part of the pin... but either way.. it should give me the alerts at least.. it's like if the button never calls the method.

Answer (score 0):

fixed it like this.

```
 <asp:Button CssClass="button" ID="CalcCoord_Btn" runat="server" Text="Calcular Coordenadas" OnClientClick="javascript: calculateCoordinates();"/>


 var calculateCoordinates = function() {
     alert("calculateCoordinates");
     var AddressLn1 = document.getElementById("AddressLine1");
     var AddressLn2 = document.getElementById("AddressLine2");
     var State = document.getElementById("State");
     var Town = document.getElementById("City");
     var Postcode = document.getElementById("ZipCode");
     var Country = document.getElementById("State");


     var address = AddressLn1.value + ', ';
     address += AddressLn2.value + ', ';
     address += Town.value + ', ';
     address += Postcode.value + ', ';
     address += Country.value;

     // Make REST call to get geocoded information (that is, the coordinates for the address)
     // This will use your call back procedure and return result in JSON format
     var geocodeRequest = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?query=" + encodeURI(address) + "&output=json&jsonp=GeocodeCallback&key=" + credentials;
     CallRestService(geocodeRequest);
     return false;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try with onclick event instead of onClientClick.
May this will help !!!